# jQuery Detecting when list item is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, counter

I would like to append li to a ul with a button. Then as each new list item is added the number of list items is displayed. I can add the li but don't know where to go from there.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>List counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="myUL">
    </ul>
    <button class="myBUTTON">Add List Item</button>
    <p>List count>#</p>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('button.myBUTTON').on('click', function(eval) {
            eval.preventDefault();
        $('ul.myUL').append('<li>Item 1</li>');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `length` to get the `li` count and set it in the `click` listener.

```js
$('.myBUTTON').on('click', function() {
    // get the length before and directly increment by one to set it to the elements
    var length = ++$('.myUL li').length;

    $('.myUL').append('<li>Item ' + length  + '</li>');
    $('p').text('List count ' + length );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="myUL"></ul>
<button class="myBUTTON">Add List Item</button>
<p>List count 0</p>
```

Comment: Thanks eisbehr that helps